# Format(SomeDate,"MM/dd") = "12-15" in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm writing a VBA macro in Excel that analyzes data from the spreadsheet and sends an email. In this macro, I have to attach the date formatted as "MM/dd" but the output is in the format of "MM-dd". So the question is, why is my slash getting replaced with a dash?

For simplicity, I have reduced the code to this example, and verified the problem exists with this example as well...

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim Yesterday As Date: Yesterday = DateAdd("d", -1, Now)
    MsgBox Format(Yesterday, "MM/dd")
End Sub
```

When run, the message box shows "12-15" instead of "12/15" as expected.

Comment: I used the exact same code and I get "12/15" as expected. That's unusual...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I haven't used VBA myself, but I *suspect* it's treating `/` as "the current culture's date separator" - and you're presumably executing in a culture which uses `-` as the date separator. You could try <strike>quoting</strike> escaping the slash if you definitely *always* want a slash:

```
MsgBox Format(Yesterday, "MM\/dd")
```

That's a bit of a guess at both the cause and the fix, but it's at least worth a try.

EDIT: Thanks to GSerg for the correction of how to perform the right escaping in this context.

Comment: Your guess is entirely correct, it's just the escaping, it's done with a slash: `"MM\/dd"`

Comment: You could be correct about the culture settings. I have my date format set to `yyyy-MM-dd` in my regional settings. Adding the the quotation marks as you suggested resulted in `12'-'14` though.

Comment: +1 nice answer and boy, it's not every day we see you here in the VBA/Excel section of the site, Jon! ^o^/

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with your culture settings in Windows. Go to Control Panel - Regional and Language Options - Customize Regional Options - Date seperator. It's set to "-". If you prefer "/" you can change it there.

If you wish to format the date regardless of your default regional settings, you can do what Jon Skeet has said (escape the character).

Answer (score 2):

The forward slash has a special meaning in date formats. It stands for the date separator as defined by regional settings. You can indicate that you *literally* want that separator by prefixing it with a backslash:

```
MsgBox Format(Yesterday, "MM\/dd")
```

According to the [documentation on the `Format`  function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications):

> (`/`) **Date separator.** In some locales, other characters may be used to represent the date separator. The date separator separates the day, month, and year when date values are formatted. The actual character used as the date separator in formatted output is determined by your system settings.
>
> (`\`) Display the next character in the format string. To display a character that has special meaning as a literal character, precede it with a backslash (`\`). The backslash itself isn't displayed. Using a backslash is the same as enclosing the next character in double quotation marks. To display a backslash, use two backslashes (`\\`). Examples of characters that can't be displayed as literal characters are the date-formatting and time-formatting characters (a, c, d, h, m, n, p, q, s, t, w, y, /, and :), the numeric-formatting characters (#, 0, %, E, e, comma, and period), and the string-formatting characters (@, &, <, >, and !).

Comment: very nice you posted this explenation. Thank you!