# Problem with value as date and format as text in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a Macro where I need two things in one of the column ranges:

a) Cell values must be the date of the next day in the dd/mm/yyyy format;

b) Cell Format must be text

I keep running into the problem of the date format being changed to mm/dd/yyyy.

Default excel format for the vba function date is dd/mm/yyyy ,since my excel language is set to Portuguese.

By running:

```
Sub format()
  Range("A1").Value = Date + 1
End Sub
```

I get the value  11/02/2023, date format, which is expected. But if I run:

```
Sub format2()
  Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@" 
  Range("A1").Value = Date + 1
End Sub
```

The output is 02/11/2023 in text, in the mm/dd/yyyy format. I'd like to understand why  this would even happen

Comment: Try the NumberFormat `dd/mm/yyyy;;;@` for a combination?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens for me. Not sure why but you can achieve what you want by doing:

```
Sub format2()
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("A1").Value = format(Date + 1, "dd\/mm\/yyyy")
End Sub
```

This will result in the cell being formatted as text in format "dd/mm/yyyy".

If you wanted the same format but actually formatted as date, you should do this:

```
Sub format2()
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd\/mm\/yyyy;@"
    Range("A1").Value = Date + 1
End Sub
```

The backslashes are there because excel (at least on my system) considers the forward slash a substitute for default separator and replaces it with hyphens, which are my actual default separators.

I'd like to credit this answer for the last point (escaping the forward slashes): https://stackoverflow.com/a/8527762/9852011